# NAS running Ubuntu / Raid 5 / SSD cache

Tags: ssd, raid, swap, nas, flashcache

I'm about to setup a NAS - planned hardware so far:

- MB: ASUS P9D WS(*link1): sry, it's german, it says th MB supports Hot-Plug in AHCI or RAID Mode, supports Intel Smart Response (SSD Caching)
- CPU: Intel Core i5-4570TE Processor
  (first I thought about Intel Xeon Processor E3-1220L v2, but I could not find any 1155 sockel MB with 6x SATA III interfaces / just 3x SATA III)
- HDD: 3x WD30EFRX(*link2) (Western Digital Red 3TB) - I'm pretty sure this disk supports hot swapping as it was designed for NASusage
- RAM: not sure yet, something like Crucial DIMM 4GB, DDR3L-1600, CL9, ECC

The (HD) hot swapping function with an Ubuntu `raid5` system is possible, if the hw allows it. [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1665290)

Just one open question left (not at all ubuntu related - maybe somebody knows it though):

- How much SSD space is necessary to make the cache useful?

Thanks for your inputs ;-)

*link1: future-x.de/asus-p8z77-ws-mainboard-atx-lga1155-socket-z77-usb-30-2-x-gigabit-lan-onboard-grafik-hd-audio-8-kanal-p-71172/

*link2: wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-771442.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to install Ubuntu on a server since you talk about RAID 5. The questions you asked are more inherent to your hardware than to Ubuntu.

- Yes, you can use RAID 5 with Ubuntu (I am using it)
- SSD cache depends on your HDD. You can leave the cache and swap settings by default during installation.
- You can not use hot-swapping with RAID 5 (it is something you can do if you raid your HDDs with RAID 1, instead.  But as I said, it has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Advice: choose Ubuntu Server edition (not Desktop)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is always "how much can you afford"? Don't buy the cheap stuff. There's SLC and there's MLC. An 80 GB SLC is within an agreeable price point for most. Just wing it, don't fret over the metrics. Sounds like you're not serving up a filer for some global enterprise vpn with a hundred thousand requests per second here...

I hope you're not doing anything important with that build. SATA vs enterprise class SAS, hot-swap vs. hot-SPARE, on-board HBA (it's proprietary software-based RAID that uses the CPU/RAM on mobo) as opposed to a hardware RAID controller with BBU, 3 drive RAID 5...when failed is nearly impossible to rebuild on this platform - get at least a 4th drive!